# Compass Bootstrap CSS cache issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, vagrant, compass

I'm currently running Compass and Bootstrap 3 through a Vagrant VM Box.

I've managed to successfully setup the project using both the Compass and Bootstrap Gem's.

I've now started writing my styles. Upon save I can see which files have been modified and if a the CSS has been re-compiled through SuperPuTTY, when using `compass watch --poll`. However, when either compiling via `compass watch` or through `compass compile`, I only occasionally see the changes through my browser.

I don't believe this to be a browser caching issue, as I've turned it off via dev tools, I've also tried clearing the cache, as well as directly opening up the newly compiled CSS and adding a `?1234` cache buster to the end of the URL. I'm also getting no errors upon compile (these are also normally displayed within SuperPuTTY).

I have a suspicion the problem may lay in the bootstrap plugin as this `require 'bootstrap-sass'` is loaded in the config.rb file, I'm currently investigating this.

Is anyone aware of any fixes for this, or aware of any issues/bugs with Compass compiling the Bootstrap SCSS code?

/------ UPDATE ------/

After further investigation this seems to be a caching issue. The file seems to be correct on the server after compiling, but when it arrives at the browser it seems to retain the old version. The browser cache is disabled, this is where my confusion now lays, as it should request a new file upon refresh.

Answer (score 0):

We seemed to have fixed the problem by adding a no-cache rule for our header, and also disabling sendfile in the Apache vhosts file. This combination seems to have resolved the issue